# What is the correct way of running JBoss as a service

Tags: java, jboss, aix

I'm running an APP under JBoss on AIX 6, and the correct way to run JBoss, as the docs says, is using the ./run.sh script, but said script runs on front, not on the background, and also gives a lot of debug info to stdout, instead to logfile, and any ctrl+c or closing or whatever will break it...

How do I put it on background correctly and send that logging to another place?

Answer (score 3):

In `bin` dir you can find such three scripts:

```
jboss_init_hpux.sh
jboss_init_redhat.sh
jboss_init_solaris.sh
```

These scripts allow you to run JBoss as a service. Unfortunately I have no idea if it works for AIX but maybe you can use one of these scripts as a starting point to create your own. At least you will see how they start JBoss in background.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get it to run after you exit:  Start it with `nohup`, end it with `&`
2. To get a log: after the &, redirect stdout and stderr thusly:  `> my.file.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

The debug logs should be really easy to fix.

add

```
<priority value="INFO"/>
```

in the definition of the root logger in the jboss-log4j.xml